# Python3: How to "not" round to nearest even?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know that Python3's round() function rounds to the nearest even.

How can I prevent that and make it round half away from zero as Python2 did?

Comment: How should -1.5 be rounded?

Comment: @TimPietzcker, OP says both "half away from zero" and "as Python2 did", so `-1.5` should be rounded to `-2.0`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker It should be rounded to -2.

Comment: That's what I thought. So `math.ceil()` is not the way to go...

Comment: That's not the only reason it's not the way to go... the `2.2` example in the answer below is just plain wrong. `2.2` should never round to `3`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Decimal` and `ROUND_HALF_UP` from [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#module-decimal)

```
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_HALF_UP

print(Decimal(2.5).quantize(0, ROUND_HALF_UP)) # 3
print(Decimal(-2.5).quantize(0, ROUND_HALF_UP)) # -3
```

Comment: No I mean the method that always rounds up when a .5 is given, not the ceil() function.

Comment: @guhet5ty3984wefjn Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Another option is shown [here](http://python3porting.com/differences.html#rounding-behavior) after the "If you need the Python 2 behavior". Copying the relevant code:

```
import math
def my_round(x, d=0):
    p = 10 ** d
    if x > 0:
        return float(math.floor((x * p) + 0.5))/p
    else:
        return float(math.ceil((x * p) - 0.5))/p
```